# Keras: ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal (VGGNets)

Tags: python, keras, machine-learning

Estoy siguiendo un [tutorial](https://youtu.be/7n1SpeudvAE) y cargué el modelo `VGGNet16` pre-entrenado usando `Keras`

```
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()

model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers:
  model.add(layer)

model.layers.pop()

for layer in model.layers:
  layer.trainable = False

model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predict'))
#model.summary()
```

Usé `model.save('path/model_1.h5')` para salvar el modelo después de entrenarlo con `model.fit_generator(...)`

Entonces me quede sin tiempo en `Colaboratory`. así que quise usar `model = load_model('path/model_1.h5')` para cargar de nuevo mi modelo en lugar de cargarlo como mostré previamente con `vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()...`

Y ahora estoy teniendo este error:

> ```
> ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 4096 and
> 1000. Shapes are [4096,10] and [1000,10]. for 'Assign_61' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [4096,10], [1000,10].
> ```

Qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)

Comment: @RubialesAlberto Mi pregunta es de hace dos años (2018). Porque es marcada como duplicada por una pregunta realizada hace 22 dias (2020)?. Mi pregunta fue respondida hace rato, ya ni trabajo en ese proyecto...

Comment: Hola Virtualdvid! no te lo tomes a mal no es por ti, la pregunta y la respuesta están genial :)  Simplemente es por limpiar el sitio se ha creado una pregunta/respuesta canónica que aglutina este tipo de error, que es genérico, así en el futuro las personas que tengan este tipo de error, podrán encontrarla fácilmente y saber que les está indicando. Puedes ver más sobre ello en [¿Son duplicadas preguntas por errores de sintaxis?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4898/son-duplicadas-preguntas-por-errores-de-sintaxis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a la gente de [@deeplizard](https://twitter.com/deeplizard) por ayudarme a encontrar esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482483/valueerror-when-loading-a-previously-saved-retrained-vgg16-model-using-keras) en la versión de inglés de StackOverflow.

Acá la traducción:

El problema es con la linea `model.layers.pop()`. cuando usamos `.pop` para saltar una linea directa de la capa `model.layers`, La topologia de este modelo no es actualizada acordemente. Por consiguiente todas las operaciones siguientes serán malas, dándonos usa definición errónea del modelo.

Especificamente, cuando añadimos una capa con `model.add(layer)`, la lista `model.outputs` es actualizada para ser la salida del tensor de la capa. Pueden encontrar las siguientes lineas en la fuente del código de `Sequential.add()`:

```
        output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
        # ... skipping irrelevant lines
        self.outputs = [output_tensor]
```

Cuando llaman `model.layers.pop()`, Sin embargo, `model.outputs` no es actualizado acordemente como un resultado, la nueva capa añadida será llamada con una mala entrada del tensor (porque `self.outputs[0]` continua siendo la salida del tensor de la capa removida).

Esto puede ser demostrado con las siguientes lineas:

```
model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers:
    model.add(layer)

model.layers.pop()
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

print(model.layers[-1].input)
# => Tensor("predictions_1/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 1000), dtype=float32)
# the new layer is called on a wrong input tensor

print(model.layers[-1].kernel)
# => <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(1000, 3) dtype=float32_ref>
# the kernel shape is also wrong
```

La incorrecta forma del núcleo (kernel) es el porque estamos viendo el error de incompatibilidad de tamaño en los arreglos `[4096,3]` versus `[1000,3]`.

Para resolver este problema, simplemente no añada la ultima capa a la secuencia del modelo `Sequential`.

```
model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-1]:
    model.add(layer)
```